# Need to store many values on the basis of one key

Tags: collections

I have a scenario in which i have to store multiple values like fName,lName and emailAddress corresponding to one id which is primary. In simple terms i m fetching data from database and want to store it in HashMap like Map> 
please suggest me how i do it.

Ex:-

Lets suppose we have data like

ID     FName      LName        EmailAddress
1      Tom        Marshell    tmarshell@ABC.com

and want it in HashMap like:- 1, [Tom,Marshell,tmarshell@ABC.com], please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want is to make a class with 3 instance variables fName, lName and emailAddress. Now instead of directly storing the values in HashMap, store objects of that class. For eg.

```
class Person {
    String fName,
    String lName,
    String emailAddress,

    public Person(String lName, String fName, String emailAddress){
        this.lName = lName;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    // getter and setter methods below ....
    ....
}
```

Now you can use it like -

```
Map<Integer,Person> map = new HashMap<>();
Person p1 = new Person("Tom", "Marshell", "TMarshell@ABC.com"); // Or 
populate it from database
map.put(1,p1);
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your requirements, I think we just create an Object to store fName/iName/email etc, right? I guess it's not that simple as I thought.

Thanks